# echo with 5 images as background-image

Tags: php, image

I have an echo that reads

```
echo '<img src="'.$images[$key].'" id="layer" />';
```

It shows 5 semi transparent png's, which the css id lays over each other with a position:absolute.

is there a way to display this specific echo as background-image for the whole page? Thanks.

Comment: 5 images at the same time? or random?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<script>document.body.style.backgroundImage = "' . $images[$key] . '";</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will merge two `PNGs` files in one. You can use a for loop to combined the rest

```
$image1 = imagecreatefrompng('a.png');
$image2 = imagecreatefrompng('b.png');
imagecopymerge($image1, $image2, 0, 0, 75, 75, 150, 150, 100);
```